# Why NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions returning FALSE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networkextension

did you know what am I missing in my code and settings when I try to call the registerWithOptions it always return false?

I already have the NetworkExtension Entitlement.

I've already created an Entitlement
[image]

And already created an array in .plist
[image]

here is my code:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Try here", kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName, nil];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp.ex", 0);

BOOL isAvailable = [NEHotspotHelper registerWithOptions:options queue:queue handler: ^(NEHotspotHelperCommand * cmd) {

    NSLog(@"Sucessfully Registered");
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your app is signing with the correct entitlements file. You can do this with the following command:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-atpabrbgvqunorhiggpf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppName.app
```

In the output, you should see the two following entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.HotspotHelper</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
<array>
```

If you don't you can debug your codesigning process by following the thread here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/75928#75928

Remember the hotspot helper code will only run on a device.

For reference, this code works for me (Swift)

```
var options = [String: NSObject]()
        options[kNEHotspotHelperOptionDisplayName] = "Try Here" as NSObject?

        NSLog("Lets register", "")
        let returnType = NEHotspotHelper.register(options: options, queue: DispatchQueue.main, handler: {(_ cmd: NEHotspotHelperCommand) -> Void in

            NSLog("Returned", "")



            print(cmd)

            if cmd.commandType == NEHotspotHelperCommandType.evaluate || cmd.commandType == NEHotspotHelperCommandType.filterScanList {


                if cmd.networkList != nil {

                    for network: NEHotspotNetwork in cmd.networkList! {

                        NSLog("Found network \(network.bssid) with \(network.ssid)", "")

                        if (network.ssid == "Hub") {

                            print("Confidence set to high for ssid:\(network.ssid)")
                        }
                    }

                }



            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the answer above, you must put this your Info.plist

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
   <string>network-authentication</string>
</array>
```